# Error Uploading APK File to Google Play Console because it Keep Saying I Have the Wrong Certificate

Tags: apk, google-play-console, code-signing-certificate

I am using Google Play Console to upload my app. Whenever I upload the APK file, this is the message that I keep getting:

**You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate.**

**[ SHA1: 88:50:D6:16:J3:3B:94:47:03:10S:33:A4:0Z:S6:8F:4L:21:B3:Q3:0V ] 
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: 22:1X:1K:22:D2:11:Z7:V0:22:1Q:B4:S3:K7::H6:NN:NN:6Y:32:W7 ]**

I need help with this. It is a big set back for me. Thanks.

Note well: These are Fake Certificate Numbers that are just used for illustration purposes. :)

Looking forward for substantial help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enroll in "App Signing by Play" (you can verify this from the App Signing page of the Play Console)?

If yes, you may have been prompted to create an "upload key" at this time. That's the keystore you should be using to sign APKs uploaded to the Play Console.

If no, or if you haven't created an upload key, you need to upload an APK signed with the same keystore as the first APK you uploaded. Have you reinstalled Studio and created a new keystore by any chance?

Note that it's possible to have multiple keys stored in the same keystore as well, so make sure you enter the alias of key correctly as well. In Studio, the default is "key0".

Comment: Pierre, Thanks for responding. Yes I am enrolled in "App Signing by Play." How to use the keystore to sign the APK? I have created many APK's and I kept getting the same error for my upload.